# DateTime content '\/Date(08-03-2022T00:48:07:497Z)\/' does not start with '\/Date(' and end with ')\/' as required for JSON

Tags: java, json, datetime

I'm looking to make an API call in a Java 8 project, however, when I attempt to make the call, the API responds with the following error message:
*DateTime content '08-03-2022T00:48:07:497Z' does not start with '\/Date(' and end with ')\/' as required for JSON.*

Seems like a fairly easy fix, right? So I tried to add the formatting myself:

```
            OffsetDateTime offsetDateTime = date.toInstant().atOffset(ZoneOffset.UTC);
            DateTimeFormatter DATE_TIME_FORMATTER = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MM-uuuu'T'HH:mm:ss:SSSXXXXX");
            String dateStringInUTC = offsetDateTime.format(DATE_TIME_FORMATTER);

            Entry entry = Entry.builder()
                    .dateTime("\\/Date(" + dateStringInUTC + ")\\/")
                    .departmentId(departmentId)
                    .userId(userId)
                    .build();
```

For reference, here is the Entry class:

```
import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;

@Getter
@Setter
@Builder
public class Entry {

    @JsonProperty("DateTime")
    public String dateTime;
    @JsonProperty("DepartmentId")
    public DepartmentId departmentId;
    @JsonProperty("UserId")
    public UserId userId;

    
}
```

Yet (this part made me giggle) the API responds with the same error (with updated formatting):
*DateTime content '\/Date(08-03-2022T00:48:07:497Z)\/' does not start with '\/Date(' and end with ')\/' as required for JSON.*

I saw some other similar posts regarding this topic, but those seemed to be in C# and I don't believe the particular Class they were referencing as a solution quite translated to Java.

I copy-pasted my manually formatted string *\/Date(08-03-2022T00:48:07:497Z)\/* into a Postman request, and that request went through just fine via Postman. But no such luck when put into practice in the Java solution.

Comment: Well, it looks peculiar to me that the string `08-03-2022T00:48:07:497Z`, *looks* like an ISO 8601 date time format, but isn't. It should be `2022-08-03T00:48:07.497Z`.

Comment: Anyway, the real reason you get this error seems to be that you need to get rid of the backslashes. It should probably be `/Date(...)/`.

Comment: `Date(...)` isn't the same as `Date('...')` based on the error message